# How do I read a gzipped CSV file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have tried many libraries, but it seems that I cannot get the types to match.

Typical attempt:

```
using SomeLib, CSV
fh = SomeLib.open("gzipped_file.gz")
CSV.read(fh) # error
```

Example:

```
using CodecZlib
CSV.read(GzipDecompressorStream(open("gzipped_file.gz")))
# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching position(::TranscodingStreams.TranscodingStream{GzipDecompressor,IOStream})
```

Comment: Seems that `CodecZlib` does not implement all `IO` API that `CSV.read` relies on. Probably it is worth to make an Issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the meantime you can use CSVFiles.jl:

```
using CSVFiles, DataFrames, FileIO

open("yourfile.csv.gz") do io
    load(Stream(format"CSV", GzipDecompressorStream(io))) |> DataFrame
end
```

Comment: Is `Using CodecZlib` required for `GzipDecompressorStream`?

Comment: This is an old answer. Here https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/pull/864 you have the state of the issue - in short: very soon (days) you will be able to read gzipped files out of the box with CSV.jl.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Bogumił's answer, you can do the following as well:

```
using CSV
using GZip

df = GZip.open("some_file.csv.gz", "r") do io
    CSV.read(io)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple:

```
using CSVFiles, DataFrames
df = DataFrame(load(File(format"CSV", "data.csv.gz")))
```

Answer (score 0):

My new package [TableReader.jl](https://github.com/bicycle1885/TableReader.jl) supports transparent gzip, xz, and zstd decompression. So, the following code will work as you expect:

```
using TableReader

readcsv("path/to/file.csv.gz")
readcsv("path/to/file.csv.xz")
readcsv("path/to/file.csv.zst")
```